# Error in IF results

Tags: excel-formula

I would like help with an `if` formula for if we have people of age 45 or more and their years of service is 2 years or more I have to be able to do a vlookup of 2 years and give a result of notice period of a termination employee.

- Age is in H24 is 45
- Year of service is in C61 is 1
- Table of 2 for year in R73 and the notice period weeks in V73 of 1.

I have put `in =IF(H24>=45,C61>=2,VLOOKUP(2,R73:V73,5,))`, this results in FALSE not the result of 0.

If I change Years of service to 2 I get -
I have put `in =IF(H24>=45,C61>=2,VLOOKUP(2,R73:V73,5,))`, this results in FALSE not the result of 0.

If I change Years of service to 1 or 2 and ago to 43 I get -
I have put `in =IF(H24>=45,C61>=2,VLOOKUP(2,R73:V73,5,))`, this results in FALSE not the result of 1.

Help!!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your IF statement should be structured like this:

```
=IF(AND(H24>=45, C61>=2), Value-If-True, Value-If-False)
```

Because you want the employee to be 45 or over, and the years of service to be 2 or more.

Also you need to double check your VLOOKUP behaves as expected by testing it outside of an IF block, like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(2,R73:V73,5)
```

Check if that result is what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much not quite right in the question that picking it apart may have some educational value.

The upper block in the image below represents the syntax you were using and why the results of your three tests were what you found (except that I think the second test would have returned TRUE rather than FALSE):

[image: SO14868030 example]

The first element of the syntax of the [IF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx) function is a *logical_test*. Where that is `H24>=45` and H24 is 45 the *value_if_true* (ticked, upper branch) is evaluated (as for your first two tests). For the first test C61 was `1` so `=C61>=2` returned FALSE, as you noted. For the second test I believe it would have returned TRUE (though you wanted a number).

For your third test the *logical_test* failed and the second (with a cross, lower branch) was taken. This hit a mishap with a VLOOKUP function.

In the lower block is a representation of @Samuel's construction. Here the *logical_test* is compound - both elements ([AND](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/and-function-HP010069828.aspx)) must 'pass' to proceed to the upper branch, with the *value_if_false* in the image set to `0`.

However there is also a problem or two with [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx). The `V` is for vertical and the range provided is horizontal. So whatever search term is used (*lookup_value* - `2` in the upper block) the result is always going to be whatever is in V73, which from your testing would appear to be `FALSE` or something that returned FALSE. The link mentions that for *table_array* "Two or more columns of data" are required.

The value in V73 is returned partly because the fourth parameter (*range_lookup*) in the lookup function has not been entered, when `TRUE` is assumed for it. In which case "an exact or approximate match is returned". If an exact match is not found "the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned" - provided the range is sorted ascending, otherwise "VLOOKUP may not give the correct value".

Hence for the lookup function you need to decide whether VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP according to your data layout, expand to at least two columns or rows and, probably, add `FALSE` as the fourth (*range_lookup*) parameter.